# How to give a unique number to add new product on website

Tags: php, time, unique-key

I am creating a ecommerce website, there i want to give a unique number to the product while adding. I want to do it in a way that it will automatically takes the number for this right now i m using time() function. with this a product get the time value while adding. But i dont know that with time function every time it will give a unique number or it can be repeat also if any body added product in a same time.

if any body have any other suggestion to give unique number or id to it pls tell me.

a reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Are they stored in a database? Have you ever used an `auto_increment` column?

Comment: mysql also has UUID(), which has its uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using time() as mentioned will give you a sortable way to create unique IDs. Concatenating strings will also further randomize your desired result and still keep it sortable:

```
$uniqueId= time().mt_rand();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother using `time()` to uniquely name your products. Just use an MySQL **auto_increment** column and then if you need to retrieve the new ID from the database use PHP's `mysql_insert_id()` function (or the equivalent for whatever database interface you're using).

Comment: ys i can use unique_id also but with the numbers i want to give the product code also which will be prefix on the code while selecting category. like if i select the any product category from option list that category code will be prefix on that unique number. so the number will be something like this PKT33456762

Comment: Where "PKT" is your category-specific prefix and "33456762" is a unique auto-incrementing number?

Comment: its specific in the database whenever i select the category from a option list it will prefix to the number generated by time() function

Answer (score 0):

create a table with the following schema

```
create table products
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  product nvarchar(40),
  type nvarchar(10),
  time timestamp default now(),
  ...
);
```

to insert data into the table use

```
insert into products(product,type) 
values ('JEdit','Editor'),('BlueFish','Compiler');
```

Your table would look like this

```
id     product      type       time                 ...
_____________________________________________________
1      JEdit        Editor     2012-4-11 10:00:00  
2      BlueFish     Compiler   2012-4-11 11:00:00
```